# Simulated emission of photon, why same energy state?

Tags: laser, hamiltonian

I read that an incoming photon with a particular frequency can be absorbed by an already excited electron, the electron will then emits 2 similar photons with the same frequency or energy state as the incoming photon. What happens to the photon that was absorbed by the electron earlier and assume this photon has a different frequency than the incoming photon? I know the answer is Hamiltonian but what does it says in words form? Also what happens if the incoming photon has sufficient energy to eject an electron, will there be a chain reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incoming photon will induce an electronic transition  from the excited state to a lower energy level. So in the end you will have two photons: the incoming one and the one that was emitted when electron made the transition to the lower energy level.

[image]

In order for the incoming photon to induce the transition, it must have the corresponding energy $E_{2}-E_{1}$. Remember that energy levels are quantized. To induce a transition from $|2\rangle\rightarrow |1\rangle$ you must provide the energy associated with those particular energy levels. When the electron makes the transition to a lower energy level, there will be a photon emitted with the energy equal to the energy difference between the two energy levels involved.

The emitted photon will have the energy $E_{2}-E_{1}$ which is the energy that the incoming photon must have in order to induce that particular transition.

Comment: okay so unless the incident photon has exactly energy equals hv else there can be no simulated emission, so this is not cloning but triggering the emission I see. but why excited electron doesn't emit photon and must be triggered by incident photon?

Comment: @user6760, It can, that is what happens in spontaneous emission. That's why you need a metastable state so that electrons cannot de-excite too quickly. The metastable state will allow you to generate population inversion.

Comment: I think I understand we must first introduce an incident photon to excite the electron and then immediately add another similar incident photon to trigger the emission, if we keep adding incident photons so that all the electrons becomes excited and easily triggered we will have laser! thanks.